# Как можно ускорить delete 10 миллионов строк?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Есть анонимный блок на удаление 10 миллионов записей, выполняется очень долго.

Как можно ускорить его?

```
declare
batchSize number := 100000;
batchCount number;
totalCount number;
begin
select count(HD.id)
into totalCount
from BpmsHistoricDetailEntity HD
         inner join BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI
                    on HD.processInstanceId = HPI.id
where HPI.endTime is not null
  and HPI.endTime < sysdate - 1;

if totalCount < batchSize then
    batchSize := totalCount;
    batchCount := 1;
else
    batchCount := floor(totalCount / batchSize) + 1;
end if;

for i in 1..batchCount
    loop
delete from BpmsHistoricDetailEntityImpl where id in
(select HD.id from BpmsHistoricDetailEntityImpl HD
inner join BpmsHistoricProcessInstanceEntityImpl HPI on HD.processInstanceId = HPI.id
where HPI.endTime is not null and HPI.endTime <= sysdate -1
order by HD.id
fetch next batchSize rows only);
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Проверяли ли вы сам запрос на выбор ID. Он работает быстро? Есть возможность ускорить его выполнение? Есть ли индекс в таблице `BpmsHistoricDetailEntityImpl ` для колонки `processInstanceId`

Comment: Если 10 мили. будет удалено, то сколько останется в таблице?  _выполняется очень долго_, а  как долго?

Answer (score 3):

Удаление с `DELETE` это довольно дорогая операция в БД по сравнению с другими DML. Постранство от удаленных данных не освобождается автоматически, т.е. таблица будет сильно дефрагментирована, индексы разбалансированы, указатели HWM и low-HWM не переместятся. Другими словами, работать с таблицей для вставки новых данных будет крайне неэффективно.

Золотое правило -- если будет удалено ~10% и более от общего объёма данных, то будет гораздо лучше просто пересоздать таблицу с данными, которые не должны быть удалены.

Несколько упрощённый пример (это не единственный способ):

```sql
create table mytab as 
    select rownum id, sysdate-level/24/60 created from dual
    connect by level <= 10e4;

create table mytabnew nologging as
    select * from mytab where created >= trunc (sysdate)-1;

rename mytab to mytabold; 

Table renamed.

rename mytabnew to mytab; 

Table renamed.
```

Все ограничения (*constraints*), разрешения (*grants*) и индексы должны быть перенесены со старой на новую таблицу. Как убедитесь, что всё работает, то:

```
drop table mytabold purge;
```

---

Если таблица постоянно заполняется новыми данными и переодически должны быть удалены старые данные, то однозначно, таблицу надо секционировать по ключу `HPI.endTime`, чтобы удалять целые секции.